# Warning: Identity file not accessible: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, cluster-computing, public-key

I currently have access to a supercomputer cluster.
The problem starts when I enter.

When I try to perform the following command line `ssh -i user @ extension`, I get the following error

```
Warning: Identity file user @ extension not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

I have tried testing the public root key and if it recognizes it, instead when I run in `/home/user`, I get the error.
I've been trying some permission changes with the chmod command and I can't get a solution.

Answer (score 5):

`ssh -i` is to reference a private ssh key.

So if you have a key pair named `user.rsa`/`user`, that might work.

But in your case, "user" is not the name of the key, but simply the remote user you want to open a secure shell with on the remote server

```
ssh user@remoteServer
```

You don't need `-i`, if you have a default `id_rsa/id_rsa.pub` key pair in your local `~/.ssh`